# Alert is not working on tags input bootstrap using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Jquery alert is not working for `tags input` bootstrap input field.
HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="cities"  class="form-control newCity" data-role="tagsinput" />
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on('keyup mouseup', ".newCity", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('hello');

});
```

I've tried with `keyup`,`mousedown`,`mouseup`,`mouseout` nothing is working.

JS Fiddle link : [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/r9b73zda/)

Any Suggestions, Please!

Comment: bootstrap  will hide your input and create a new one for tags, read docs to handle event

Comment: @Satpal: Yeah, I've got to know that but how do we do alert on this visible input?

Comment: Use your browser dev tools, check what is actually in the DOM - and then figure out a matching selector ...

Comment: @CBroe: Okay.I will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are not doing anything in input.

Your input is hidden and bootstrap adding another element in place of your input.

Inspect the input you can see this.

See the demo:        [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9b73zda/1/)

```
$(document).on('keyup', ".bootstrap-tagsinput", function(e) {
alert('hello');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```